# TomEE Maven plugin debug w/ IntelliJ

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, vaadin, apache-tomee

I'm running a Vaadin web app using the TomEE Maven plugin.  When attempting to run debug in IntelliJ, it skips all breakpoints.

From what research I've read, it points to the debugger not attaching to the TomEE plugin.

Is there a way to do this without having to configure a standalone server?  Ideally for development, I want to keep the dev setup simple and packaged within the pom.

Answer (score 0):

if you run

```
mvn tomee:debug
```

then in intellij you configure a remote server on port 5005 and when the lisne "Listen ...5005..." is in the logs you connect/run this debug configuraton.

Then you debug in the server.